# query(Model) sqlalchemy with outerjoin has implicit distinct?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Consider the following model:

```
class Order(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Enum('Ordered', 'Delivered'), default='Ordered', nullable=False)
    skus = db.relationship('SKU', order_by='SKU.index', back_populates='order', passive_deletes=True)

class SKU(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('order.id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    order = db.relationship('Order', lazy='joined', back_populates='skus', innerjoin=True)

    index = db.Column(db.Integer)

    supplier = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

(`db` object is an instance of `SQLAlchemy` from `flask_sqlalchemy`)

Test data is three SKUs in single Order:

```
+----+---------+
| id | status  |
+----+---------+
| 10 | Ordered |
+----+---------+
+----+----------+-------+----------+
| id | order_id | index | supplier |
+----+----------+-------+----------+
| 28 |       10 |     0 |       10 |
| 29 |       10 |     1 |       10 |
| 30 |       10 |     2 |       10 |
+----+----------+-------+----------+
```

One would expect that using explicit outer join `Order` with `SKU` will produce cartesian product and return **3** rows, which is not true. This will print single "Ordered":

```
orders = Order.query.outerjoin(SKU).filter(SKU.supplier == 10).all()
for order in orders:
    print order.status
```

Even though, correct query is generated (and it returns **3** rows as expected):

```
SELECT `order`.id AS order_id, `order`.status AS order_status 
FROM `order` LEFT OUTER JOIN `SKU` ON `order`.id = `SKU`.order_id 
WHERE `SKU`.supplier = %(supplier_1)s
```

My guess that SQLAlchemy somehow detects duplicate Order objects and remove them from final list. But is this documented? What's the reasoning behind this?

Meanwhile, querying status field doesn't have this problem: **3** lines are printed here:

```
statuses = (db.session.query(Order.status).outerjoin(SKU)
              .filter(SKU.supplier == 10).all())
for (status, ) in statuses:
     print status
```

Comment: You're correct in that duplicate entities are weed out based on identity/primary key if just querying for an entity, and you've just asked for Order entities. Compare to for example `Order.query.outerjoin(SKU)...with_entities(Order, SKU)`. Cannot remember if and where this is documented, but will try and find it. The rationale might be that since the returned entities are anyway identity mapped and so a list with duplicates would just contain multiple references to the same objects, there's no point in returning such duplicates, if just querying for the entities.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, yeah, you right. Adding `with_entities(Order, SKU)` and replacing loop with `for (order, _) in orders:` solves the issue (at least for test case). I'll stick to explicit field querying, though.